# AWS hosted website: Connection Reset & Connection Timed Out Errors

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, timeout

I am facing an issue on my website since the last one month. There are intermittent 'Connection Reset/Connection Timed Out' errors.

Screenshot:

[image]

Sometimes the website works fine, most of the other times I get either of the above-mentioned errors.

I had transferred this site to AWS about 3 months back from a shared host and it worked fine for the first 2 months. Have started getting this error in the last one month, I have not made any changes to the website during this time.

I am free tier member so can't raise a technical support request with AWS. Therefore seeking help from the wonderful community here, as I have no clue what to do next.

Website: http://www.skyscraperdash.com

Comment: Is it possible that you have exceeded the limits available to free tier members? I ran a traffic capture when trying to connect to your website and it's not a pretty picture. There is frequent packet loss during the TCP handshake and I get no response after sending the HTTP GET request upstream.

Comment: Your DNS is reasonably in order http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools#dnsReport|type=domain&&value=skyscraperdash.com What webstack are you running? Any logs that provide hints? Eg.  Apache/Nginx.

Comment: It's not free tier limits, it's system configuration. You need to post a lot more details - system components (eg Nginx with Wordpress using RDS) and plus configuration and logs. However timeouts are most likely because of the web server, so post your full configuration for that. My gut feel is this is software level issue not an AWS issue. Your system appears to be completely down : http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160527_FE_f63e4df19767fbdd02ab702d05436a56/

Comment: First check the instance metrics, at least cpu, network, disk free space, cpu credit. Also, it makes sense to check ram/swap usage, however CloudWatch doesn't show this so you;ll have to check it on the server directly